# key error while creating autoscaling group amazon ec2 using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, autoscaling

I have an amazon ec2 instance I am trying to create an autoscaling group and use cloudwatch metrics etc on it.

```
import boto3
from boto3 import Session

session = Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
current_credentials = credentials.get_frozen_credentials()


if current_credentials.access_key is None:
    print("Access Key missing, use  `aws configure` to setup")
    exit()

if current_credentials.secret_key is None:
    print("Secret Key missing, use  `aws configure` to setup")
    exit()

# VPC design for multi az deployments
globalVars = {}
globalVars['REGION_NAME']              = "ap-south-1"
globalVars['AZ1']                      = "ap-south-1a"
globalVars['AZ2']                      = "ap-south-1b"
globalVars['CIDRange']                 = "10.240.0.0/23"
globalVars['az1_pvtsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.0.0/25"
globalVars['az1_pubsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.0.128/26"
globalVars['az1_sparesubnet_CIDRange'] = "10.240.0.192/26"
globalVars['az2_pvtsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.1.0/25"
globalVars['az2_pubsubnet_CIDRange']   = "10.240.1.128/26"
globalVars['az2_sparesubnet_CIDRange'] = "10.240.1.192/26"
globalVars['Project']                  = { 'Key': 'Name',        'Value': 'test1'}
globalVars['tags']                     = [{'Key': 'Owner',       'Value': 'test1'},
                                          {'Key': 'Environment', 'Value': 'Test'},
                                          {'Key': 'Department',  'Value': 'TestD'}]
# EC2 Parameters

globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID']        = "ami-00b6a8a2bd28daf19"
globalVars['EC2-InstanceType']         = "t2.micro"
globalVars['EC2-KeyName']              = "datastructutrekey.pem"

# AutoScaling Parameters
globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName']     = "ASG-Demo-LaunchConfig"
globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'] = "ASG-Demo-AutoScalingGrp"


# Creating a VPC, Subnet, and Gateway
ec2       = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2',   region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
vpc       = ec2.create_vpc(CidrBlock=globalVars['CIDRange'])
asgClient = boto3.client('autoscaling', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])
rds       = boto3.client('rds', region_name=globalVars['REGION_NAME'])

# AZ1 Subnets
az1_pvtsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_pvtsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
az1_pubsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_pubsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
az1_sparesubnet = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az1_sparesubnet_CIDRange'], AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ1'])
# AZ2 Subnet
az2_pvtsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_pvtsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])
az2_pubsubnet   = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_pubsubnet_CIDRange'],   AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])
az2_sparesubnet = vpc.create_subnet(CidrBlock=globalVars['az2_sparesubnet_CIDRange'], AvailabilityZone=globalVars['AZ2'])

# Enable DNS Hostnames in the VPC
vpc.modify_attribute(EnableDnsSupport={'Value': True})
vpc.modify_attribute(EnableDnsHostnames={'Value': True})

# Create the Internet Gatway & Attach to the VPC
intGateway = ec2.create_internet_gateway()
intGateway.attach_to_vpc(VpcId=vpc.id)

# Create another route table for Public & Private traffic
routeTable = ec2.create_route_table(VpcId=vpc.id)
rtbAssn=[]
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az1_pubsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az1_pvtsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az2_pubsubnet.id))
rtbAssn.append(routeTable.associate_with_subnet(SubnetId=az2_pvtsubnet.id))

# Create a route for internet traffic to flow out
intRoute = ec2Client.create_route(RouteTableId=routeTable.id, DestinationCidrBlock='0.0.0.0/0', GatewayId=intGateway.id)

# Tag the resources
vpc.create_tags            (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az1_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
az2_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
intGateway.create_tags     (Tags=globalVars['tags'])
routeTable.create_tags     (Tags=globalVars['tags'])

vpc.create_tags            (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-vpc'}])
az1_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-private-subnet'}])
az1_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-public-subnet'}])
az1_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az1-spare-subnet'}])
az2_pvtsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-private-subnet'}])
az2_pubsubnet.create_tags  (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-public-subnet'}])
az2_sparesubnet.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-az2-spare-subnet'}])
intGateway.create_tags     (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-igw'}])
routeTable.create_tags     (Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-rtb'}])

# Let create the Public & Private Security Groups
elbSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='elbSecGrp',
                                      Description='ElasticLoadBalancer_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

pubSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='pubSecGrp',
                                      Description='Public_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

pvtSecGrp = ec2.create_security_group(DryRun=False,
                                      GroupName='pvtSecGrp',
                                      Description='Private_Security_Group',
                                      VpcId=vpc.id
                                      )

elbSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
pubSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])
pvtSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=globalVars['tags'])

elbSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-elb-security-group'}])
pubSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-public-security-group'}])
pvtSecGrp.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key': 'Name', 'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-private-security-group'}])

# Add a rule that allows inbound SSH, HTTP, HTTPS traffic ( from any source )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=elbSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=80,
                                           ToPort=80,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )

# Allow Public Security Group to receive traffic from ELB Security group
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                                                           'FromPort': 80,
                                                           'ToPort': 80,
                                                           'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': elbSecGrp.id}]
                                                           }]
                                           )
# Allow Private Security Group to receive traffic from Application Security group
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pvtSecGrp.id,
                                           IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
                                                           'FromPort': 3306,
                                                           'ToPort': 3306,
                                                           'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': pubSecGrp.id}]
                                                           }]
                                           )

ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=80,
                                           ToPort=80,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=443,
                                           ToPort=443,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )
ec2Client.authorize_security_group_ingress(GroupId=pubSecGrp.id,
                                           IpProtocol='tcp',
                                           FromPort=22,
                                           ToPort=22,
                                           CidrIp='0.0.0.0/0'
                                           )



# The user defined code to install  WebServer & Configure them
userDataCode = """
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x
# Setting up the HTTP server 
yum install -y httpd 
service httpd start
chkconfig httpd on
groupadd www
usermod -a -G www ec2-user
cd /var/www/
# Set the permissions
chown -R root:www /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} +
# SE Linux permissive
# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
service httpd restart
echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phptestinfo.php
"""

# Create the  Public Instance
##### **DeviceIndex**:The network interface's position in the attachment order. For example, the first attached network interface has a DeviceIndex of 0
instanceLst = ec2.create_instances(ImageId=globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID'],
                                   MinCount=1,
                                   MaxCount=2,
                                   KeyName="datastructutrekey.pem",
                                   UserData=userDataCode,
                                   InstanceType=globalVars['EC2-InstanceType'],
                                   NetworkInterfaces=[
                                       {
                                           'SubnetId': az1_pubsubnet.id,
                                           'Groups': [pubSecGrp.id],
                                           'DeviceIndex': 0,
                                           'DeleteOnTermination': True,
                                           'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
                                       }
                                   ]
                                   )


# Create the Launch Configuration
# InstanceId = 'string'
asgLaunchConfig = asgClient.create_launch_configuration(
    LaunchConfigurationName=globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName'],
    ImageId=globalVars['EC2-Amazon-AMI-ID'],
    KeyName=globalVars['EC2-KeyName'],
    SecurityGroups=[pubSecGrp.id],
    UserData=userDataCode,
    InstanceType=globalVars['EC2-InstanceType'],
    InstanceMonitoring={'Enabled': False },
    EbsOptimized=False,
    AssociatePublicIpAddress=False
)

# create Auto-Scaling Group
ASGSubnets = az1_pubsubnet.id + "," +az2_pubsubnet.id
asGroup=asgClient.create_auto_scaling_group(
    AutoScalingGroupName=globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'],
    LaunchConfigurationName=globalVars['ASG-LaunchConfigName'],
    MinSize=1,
    MaxSize=3,
    DesiredCapacity=2,
    DefaultCooldown=120,
    HealthCheckType='EC2',
    HealthCheckGracePeriod=60,
    Tags=globalVars['tags'],
    VPCZoneIdentifier=ASGSubnets
    )

asgClient.create_or_update_tags(
    Tags=[
        {
            'ResourceId': globalVars['ASG-AutoScalingGroupName'],
            'ResourceType': 'auto-scaling-group',
            'Key': 'Name',
            'Value': globalVars['Project']['Value'] + '-ASG-Group',
            'PropagateAtLaunch': True
        },
    ]
)



###### Print to Screen ########
print("VPC ID                    : {0}".format(vpc.id))
print("AZ1 Public Subnet ID      : {0}".format(az1_pubsubnet.id))
print("AZ1 Private Subnet ID     : {0}".format(az1_pvtsubnet.id))
print("AZ1 Spare Subnet ID       : {0}".format(az1_sparesubnet.id))
print("Internet Gateway ID       : {0}".format(intGateway.id))
print("Route Table ID            : {0}".format(routeTable.id))
print("Public Security Group ID  : {0}".format(pubSecGrp.id))
print("Private Security Group ID : {0}".format(pvtSecGrp.id))
print("EC2 Key Pair              : {0}".format(globalVars['EC2-KeyName']))
print("EC2 PublicIP              : {0}".format(globalVars['EC2-KeyName']))
print("RDS Endpoint              : {0}".format(globalVars['Endpoint']))
###### Print to Screen ########


"""
Function to clean up all the resources
"""
def cleanAll(resourcesDict=None):
    # Delete the instances
    ids = []
    for i in instanceLst:
        ids.append(i.id)

    ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=ids).terminate()

    # Wait for the instance to be terminated
    waiter = ec2Client.get_waiter('instance_terminated')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[ids])
    ec2Client.delete_key_pair(KeyName=globalVars['EC2-KeyName'])

    # Delete Routes & Routing Table
    for assn in rtbAssn:
        ec2Client.disassociate_route_table(AssociationId=assn.id)

    routeTable.delete()

    # Delete Subnets
    az1_pvtsubnet.delete()
    az1_pubsubnet.delete()
    az1_sparesubnet.delete()

    # Detach & Delete internet Gateway
    ec2Client.detach_internet_gateway(InternetGatewayId=intGateway.id, VpcId=vpc.id)
    intGateway.delete()

    # Delete Security Groups
    pubSecGrp.delete()
    pvtSecGrp.delete()

    vpc.delete()
```

the script runs fine except for one last line I get the following output

```
VPC ID                    : vpc-047839873c2b62b51
AZ1 Public Subnet ID      : subnet-0c8db93f160c952b3
AZ1 Private Subnet ID     : subnet-00e2068c36695cf47
AZ1 Spare Subnet ID       : subnet-0521b503114f92f97
Internet Gateway ID       : igw-020b3e284d591e977
Route Table ID            : rtb-0e83e29fed23f6773
Public Security Group ID  : sg-05bbc53b9cad2a6db
Private Security Group ID : sg-028d432258e825562
EC2 Key Pair              : datastructutrekey.pem
EC2 PublicIP              : datastructutrekey.pem
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\programming \autoscaling.py", line 281, in <module>
    print("RDS Endpoint              : {0}".format(globalVars['Endpoint']))
KeyError: 'Endpoint'
```

I am not able to understand the last error which is coming in here
1) **RDS end point error** why is it coming.I login to https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=ap-south-1#igws:sort=internetGatewayId and also  https://ap-south-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=ap-south-1#vpcs: but I could not find any thing wrong here I have created test1-vpc which it is showing me. Can any one point out here why is this error coming in and how can I get rid of it. These instances which I am creating are Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type and by default ap-south-1 does not support autoscaling could this be a reason for my error.

2)Also when I do a console loging I see 4 instances running.In 2 instance name is blank while two instance come as test1-ASG-Group why 2 instance come with blank name via above script.Here is a screenshot of point 2 [image]
The last 4 instances in the image are the ones which got created the instance number 2,3 are not having any names.Which in my opinion should have been there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is a Python programming error, not an issue with your use of AWS.

Your globarVars dict does not have a value whose key is 'Endpoint' so Python throws a KeyError when you try to access `globalVars['Endpoint']`. You need to populate a value.

Also, rather than write 100s of lines of code to build AWS infrastructure, you might want to consider using [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) which allows you to write a YAML template to do the same thing.

Finally, a preferred way to populate your globalVars dictionary would be:

```
globalVars = {
  'REGION_NAME': 'ap-south-1',
  'AZ1': 'ap-south-1a',
  'AZ2': 'ap-south-1b',
  # others here
}
```